# Unable to launch program from the IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-2013

I have learned the basics of C++ but I have never used visual studio.

I would like to know why I get popup window that says "Unable to start program" and then lists a file path `C:\folder\folder\folder\../../lib/Win32DB/ProjectNameDB.lib`. (The message doesn't give me any more info, like 'the system cannot find the file specified' or anything like that.)

`ProjectNameDB.lib` exists, but not at that particular location. The project builds successfully, and the same path as above appears in the output after `TargetPath =`.

I have tried setting the project as startup, deleting `.suo` files and `vcproj.user` files, starting without debugging, and putting the location of `ProjectName.lib` in the `Output`, `Library`, `Include`, `Reference` Directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can not start one `*.lib` but one `*.exe`. So build one EXE program you should use the below steps with Visual Statio 2013:

1. start vs2013;
2. choose File -> New -> Project;
3. choose Win32 Console Application, and write your project name, click OK;
4. click Next, click Finish;
5. Now, you can write "Hello World" in 'x.cpp'(here 'x' is your project name); the following code:

   ```
   int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
   {
       printf("Hello Wrold!\n");
       return 0;
   }
   ```
6. save, build and start run it, it will print 'Hello World' in console.

`exe` file must have `main` function, but `lib` file is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So... the problem was that the project was configured to run as a static library and not as an executable.
Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General